# Difficulties with a regex pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am facing a problem regarding Regex pattern creation in order to get all the required tokens. My String value on which regex will be applied have this shape can be like this:

**Value:**

`` "DB_TABLE_LUX.field_8='bbb \' `\" dsd' and  DB_TABLE_FRA.field_1 = ' bbb dsd' and  DB_TABLE_FRA.fieldName = ' bbb dsd ' or DB_TABLE_GER.field_3=  125  " ``

**Required result:** I want to have a list of Strings having those values

```
List {
"DB_TABLE_LUX.field_8='bbb \\' `\" dsd'",
"DB_TABLE__FRA.field_1 = ' bbb dsd'",
"DB_TABLE_FRA.fieldName = ' bbb dsd '",
"DB_TABLE_GER.field_3=  125"
}
```

**The regex I used:**

```
"DB_TABLE_[a-zA-Z]{3}\\.\\w+\\s*\\=\\s*([0-9]+|(\'(\\s*\\w+\\s*)+\'))"
```

The regex above is not extracting the whole data, the first values are missing and below is the result.

```
List{
"DB_TABLE_FRA.field_1 = ' bbb dsd'",
"DB_TABLE_FRA.fieldName = ' bbb dsd '",
"DB_TABLE_GER.field_3=  125"
}
```

I want to take into account the next value.

```
DB_TABLE_LUX.field_8='bbb \\' `\" dsd'
```

Comment: I'm afraid, this could be unsolvable problem using regular language. I think you should build your own context free grammar

Answer (score 0):

Best resource I've found for any/all regex help, with 15 languages supported.  Just type in your string to match against and click "Show Matches," and then select the tokens to match on: [RegEx Help](http://www.txt2re.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments: Instead of using a horribly complex regex to extract the parts that you want, just use a very simple regex for splitting by the parts that you do *not* want.

```
String text = "DB_TABLE_LUX.field_8='bbb \' `\" dsd' and DB_TABLE_FRA.field_1 = ' bbb dsd' and DB_TABLE_FRA.fieldName = ' bbb dsd ' or DB_TABLE_GER.field_3= 125 ";
for (String s : text.split(" and | or ")) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Of course, this *might* fail if any of those fields contain the strings `and` or `or`...

Or you could use a lookahead to match everything up to the next `(and|or)DB_TABLE` or `$`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("DB_TABLE.*?(?=\\s+(?:and|or)\\s+DB_TABLE|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Result, for both cases:

```
DB_TABLE_LUX.field_8='bbb ' `" dsd'
DB_TABLE_FRA.field_1 = ' bbb dsd'
DB_TABLE_FRA.fieldName = ' bbb dsd '
DB_TABLE_GER.field_3= 125
```

Comment: Your suggestion is useful but as mentioned is the field contain **and** or **or** the operation will fail.

Answer (score 0):

If last part is numbers or character enclosed bewteen 'bbb' and 'dsd' strings you can try with:

```
DB_TABLE_(\\w){3}\\.\\w+\\s*=\\s*(\\d+|(\'\\s*bbb.+?dsd\\s*\'))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vS3iU5/1)

with output:

```
DB_TABLE_LUX.field_8='bbb ' `" dsd'
DB_TABLE_FRA.field_1 = ' bbb dsd'
DB_TABLE_FRA.fieldName = ' bbb dsd '
DB_TABLE_GER.field_3=  125
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the full string at `DB_TABLE`, then remove ending `and`, `or` and whitespaces?